# Image fromstream issue

Tags: c#, ubuntu, stream, mono, drawing

i have problems during creating image from stream. on my windows pc it forks great, on ubuntu server, it throws an error

`System.ArgumentException: A null reference or invalid value was found [GDI+ status: InvalidParameter] at System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (System.Drawing.Status) <0x00157> at System.Drawing.Image.CreateFromHandle (intptr) <0x00027> at System.Drawing.Image.LoadFromStream (System.IO.Stream,bool) <0x0002b> at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream (System.IO.Stream,bool,bool) <0x00013>`

I checked System.Drawing library setup on my server, it says that system.drawing is installed

`mono-test-install`

`Your have a working System.Drawing setup`

any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you should show us the line that actually throws the error.

Comment: here exception is thrown:

`Image img = Image.FromStream(file.Value);`

i am using nancyfx, `file` is `Nancy.HttpFile`

Comment: See this answer I posted in another thread<br/>
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39104944/6748622

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, locate the directory where is the System.Drawing.dll file (for example
 `/opt/mono-4.4.0/lib/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll`).

Create a file in the same directory called `System.Drawing.dll.config`  with the following content, updating the directory to the correct location of `libgdiplus.so`:

```
<configuration>
  <dllmap dll="gdiplus.dll" target="/opt/mono-4.4.0/lib/libgdiplus.so"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: this didn't seem to make any difference for me - how can I check that this config file is being used?

Comment: according to this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/65590173-69d7-4ca1-a313-61d1ddb4b1e2/application-settings-in-dllconfig?forum=csharpgeneral
dll.config files are not used at runtime... so I'm confused about how this would work?